# hide and show divs using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have multiple links in a page. When I click a particular link I want a div which contains the details of that link and hide all other divs associated with other link in the same page
Please find a solution may be using javascript.

Comment: Do you use jQuery? If not, why not? :-)

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ would probably be your best bet to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an Accordion. The accordion component is available for many popular javascript framwworks. my fav is [Mootools Accordion](http://demos.mootools.net/Accordion) and I am sure there is one for [jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) and [prototype](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-simple-intelligent-accordion-effect-using-prototype-and-scriptaculous/) and what not